# Each and every one of XYZ + singular / plural Verb

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I came across these two sentences :

> Each and every one of the participants **is** expected to contribute generously to the cause.
>
> Yet Each and everyone of the weird and wanky items **have** one thing in common they are all  aboslutely 100% true.

The first sentence uses a singular helping verb while the second one uses a plural helping verb.  Isn't the second sentence grammatically wrong ? *Each and everyone*  is followed by singular helping verb, correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Also "everyone" should be "every one" instead, as it is in the first sentence.

Comment: @SteveES  I read the second sentence in Longman dictionary, wondering how they could make such a mistake !

Comment: I would also think that the word *wanky* was intended to be *wonky*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, technically the second sentence is incorrect. However, I don't think most English-speaking readers would notice the mistake. In casual or spoken English, people sometimes use incorrect subject/verb agreement if it "sounds" correct. For example, a verb might agree with the nearest noun instead of the subject of the sentence.

Unfortunately, "correcting" the error would make it worse:

> Yet each and every one of the weird and wonky items **has** one thing in common...

This sounds awkward for two reasons. First, "having one thing in common" makes more sense when referring to a group of items together, not each individual item. Second, "items has" sounds like incorrect English, even though it's correct in the context of the larger sentence.